# Missing txt file from Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am working in Visual Basic 2017. I have tried to add the file to the Debug folder, but then it just shows that the txt file i[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMlEl.png)s missing. I don't have the option under the "Word Solution".. How can I make the file show up? It keeps telling me it doesn't exist.

```
 Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader
 Const FileName As String = "words.txt"
 Dim subscript As Integer
```

Comment: VBA is not the correct tag here...

Comment: Does it work if you give it the full path to the file?

Comment: Are you sure the program is running in debug mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path of the directory (Debug or Release or any other) of the *.exe file with:

```
Dim directory as String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

Using this information, you can then construct the full path with

```
Dim path As String = IO.Path.Combine(directory, FileName)

If IO.File.Exists(path) Then
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check in Windows File Explorer to see where the file actually is (notice the Copy Path on the ribbon). In File Explorer you will see that the .exe you are running is down 2 directories from the Words Project directory. The double dots in the path is an old DOS way to navigating around directories without having to type out the whole path. This tells the compiler to find the file up 2 directories from the current directory.

For testing purposes this will work. For a release version you could add the file to Resources and access it the same way in any version.

You don't need a stream for a text file. `.ReadAllLines` returns an array of the lines in the text file

```
Private Sub OpCode()

    Dim words = File.ReadAllLines("..\..\words.txt")

End Sub
```